# Why is "or" working but "and" is not in my Ember.ComputedProperty?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, boolean, computed-properties

I think I'll feel stupid once I see the answer, but I can't wrap my head around why `or` is working but `and` isn't on this `ComputedProperty`. The tutorial suggested I'd need to use `and`, but I can't figure out how I'd do that if this doesn't work.

To start with I am new to Ember and familiar but not really comfortable with javascript, which is why I assume I'm having difficulty understanding what is going on here.

I have two properties that I need to both be `true` before a button `isDisabled`. I pass each of them to their own properties that reverse their boolean state so `isDisabled` remains active on a button until the original properties are both flipped.

contact.js

```
emailAddress: '',
  message: '',

  //**original properties**
  isValid: Ember.computed.match('emailAddress', /^.+@.+\..+$/),//starts as false
  validMessage: Ember.computed.gte('message.length', 5),//starts as false

  //**my reversing boolean properties**
  notYet: Ember.computed.not('isValid'),//starts as true
  notNow: Ember.computed.not('validMessage'),//starts as true


//isDisabled must be true to be active disabling button
  isDisabled: Ember.computed.or('notYet', 'notNow'),//starts as true
```

If I put in the correct emailAddress format:

```
emailAddress = true
notYet = false
isDisabled = true //still
```

If I then put a validMessage of 5 characters or more

```
  validMessage = true
  notNow = false
  isDisabled = false //now
```

Why does "or" work for this, why doesn't "and" or "not"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats just *De Morgan's laws*.

What you want is to be the button only be enabled when both values are valid. So you want the button be be active when `isValid and validMessage`.

This means you want to button to be disabled when `not(isValid and validMessage)`.

Due to de Morgan's law this is equivalent to `(not isValid) or (not validMessage)`.

Because `notYet` is equal to `not isValid` it follows that `(not isValid) or (not validMessage)` is equal to `notYet or (not validMessage)`.

And because `notNow` is equal to `not validMessage` it follows that `notYet or (not validMessage)` is equal to `notYet or notNow`.

And thats exactly your `isDisabled`. Thats why your code works. Just simple math. And of course in this context `notYet or notNow` would be something else. However this would be equivalent:

```
isEnabled: Ember.computed.and('isValid', 'validMessage'),
isDisabled: Ember.computed.not('isEnabled'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure whether I understand your question correctly; but as far as I understand you want `isDisabled` to be true only when both of your original values (`isValid` and `validMessage`) are true. What you need to do is either "AND these two properties" or "NOT the ORed result of NOT of each values). You can see the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b0874ee60140a2e31518b64ec681dece?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) I prepared and see everything (ANDing, NOTing, etc.) related with computed properties is working as expected. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding. In short what I'm saying is "My code works, I don't understand why my code works."